# XenServer: How to add network?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, xen, xenserver

I have a server with xensource 5.6 installed. This server has two NICs eth0 (private LAN IP) and eth1 (public IP).

I installed ubuntu 10.10 and associated with the eth1, but how can I set a public IP? I configure it but im not able to ping the gateway.

I use XenCenter as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu have to  make a NAT   to redirect real IP to  xen local ip.

Comment: How can I make that ntrance?

Comment: That NAT is in the firewall or internally in the XEN?

Comment: http://www.howtoforge.com/nat_iptables